# REGEX join in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm setting up a dataset where I use a master table which has the name of the sales person, the id and name of the chain of stores and  the name of each brand they have, like this sample data:

```
salesperson  chain_id  chain_name        brand_name
pepito          28      chairs4all          sitnice
jaimito         34      eatdrinkeat         Drink & eat
pepito          28      chairs4all          AwwwChairs!
susanita        56      something           Anything
jaimito         567     last                 One
```

In another table I have a column with each store name on it and I want to append each store to its brand . But store name may have  the location appended or other information, like this sample data from the other table:

```
store_name
sitnice
AwwwChairs! Seville
One 34
SitNice nº12
Drink & eat North road 23
```

I want the final table like this:

```
salesperson  chain_id  chain_name        brand_name        store_name
pepito          28      chairs4all          sitnice          sitnice
jaimito         34      eatdrinkeat         Drink & eat   Drink & eat North     
pepito          28      chairs4all          AwwwChairs!   AwwwChairs! Seville    
susanita        56      something           Anything          null
jaimito         567     last                 One               one 34
pepito          28      chairs4all          sitnice          SitNice nº12
```

So I think I must do a join of the two tables of brand_name and store name. I tried this:

```
    SELECT brand_name, salesperson, chain_name, chain_id, store_name   
FROM data
    cross join
     data2
    where
    brand_name like CONCAT('%', store_name,'%')
```

This did not return the expected result. It returned way less records than expected and only matched some of the expected records. I also tried REGEXP_CONTAINS and forced another joins, but as I had no other filed to join on, it worked really poorly.
Thanks

Comment: Show sample data from _both_ tables and examples of which matches did work and, crucially, which did not. Don't just make readers guess at why (case sensitivity? invisible characters between normal ones? who knows?) some unknown joins seemed to fail, please! Anyway, you probably want a 'normal' `join on`, not a `cross join where`; what you have right now seems like a strange hybrid of the obsolete pre-ANSI syntax and 'real' `join`s.

Comment: I cant possibly use a normal join as there is not a common field, can I? Or if you may tell me how I'll really grateful. I'll put an example of the other table, though it's quite explicitly written in the question

Comment: I don't know what "comon field" you think is missing? We join by comparing a value in 1 table to a value in another. That comparison needn't be `=`. Try `inner join data2 on data.brand_name like concat('%', data2.store_name, '%')`. _Buuut_... now I see the clarification that `data2` might contain typos, not just extra stuff at start or end: you're in for a horrifying journey into fuzzy string matching, which hopefully ends in the data being cleansed & normalised properly so you'll never have to do such matching again... :-) If you are seeing failures to match absent typos, again, post examples

Comment: It will be impossible to answer this question unless you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I agree with @FelipeHoffa, could you please provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I provided the desired result. The sample data was already in the question wasnt it? Otherwise I don't undertand exactly what data you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample data I was able to create a StandardSQL query to achieve the desired output. I have uploaded in BigQuery two tables one called `chain_name` and the second table `store_name` with the 1st and 2nd chunk of data you shared, respectively.

In order to CROSS JOIN the 2 tables analysing if `brand_name` is inside `store_name`(which may contain the the store's address in addition to the brand_name), I have used the [HAVING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#having_clause) clause, which filters out the rows that do not return **TRUE** when they are evaluated against a bool expression. Also, [REGEX_CONTAINS()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) which returns true if the analysed expressions are a partial match.

Below is the query,

```
SELECT salesperson, chain_id, chain_name, brand_name, store_name FROM `project_id.dataset.store_name` 
CROSS JOIN `project_id.dataset.chain_name`
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
HAVING REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(store_name),lower(brand_name))
ORDER BY chain_id
```

And the output,

```
Row salesperson chain_id    chain_name  brand_name  store_name
1   pepito      28          chairs4all  sitnice     sitnice
2   pepito      28          chairs4all  AwwwChairs! AwwwChairs! Seville
3   pepito      28          chairs4all  sitnice     SitNice nº12
4   jaimito     34          eatdrinkeat Drink & eat Drink & eat North road 23
5   jaimito     567         last        One         One 34
```

Notice that [LOWER()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#lower) is used in order to match the names even though there might be some lower/caption letters difference.

Comment: Nice!! Worked like a charm, plus I learned about Having function, really thankful for this! Thanks!